# How Erasure Coding used in hadoop3 and how they achieve fault tolerance with it?

Tags: hadoop, replication, hadoop3

As per the Hadoop 3.x release notes, they have introduced **Erasure coding** to overcome the problems with storage.

> Erasure coding, a new feature in HDFS, can reduce storage overhead by approximately 50% compared to replication while maintaining the same durability guarantees.

can someone explain me how Erasure coding is used in fault tolerant way with less space overhead?

Comment: They have an entire article dedicate to it. You can read that here : https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSErasureCoding.html

Answer (score 1):

To understand the how HDFS Erasure Coding works and reduces the storage space.

Refer: “[Introduction to HDFS Erasure Coding in Apache Hadoop](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/09/introduction-to-hdfs-erasure-coding-in-apache-hadoop/)”.